# Do lycanthropes need to do damage in order to inflict the curse?

Tags: dnd-5e, lycanthropy

I'd like to clarify whether were-creatures need to do damage in order to have a chance of inflicting the lycanthropy curse.

Considering the creature stats in isolation it would appear the answer is *no*.
E.g. For the werewolf (all other lycanthropes are similar):

> **Bite** ... *Hit:* 6 (1d8 + 2) piercing damage. If the target is a humanoid, it must succeed on a DC 12 Constitution saving throw or be cursed  with werewolf lycanthropy.

From the above, the possibility of being afflicted applies *whenever* the bite attack hits. So if damage reduction or immunities kick in, and the target takes *zero* damage, there's still a possibility of getting the curse.

However, page 206 of the MM also states:

> **Curse of Lycanthropy.** A humanoid creature can be afflicted with the curse of lycanthropy after being wounded by a lycanthrope.

The keyword here is *wounded*, which implies that the attack must actually deal *damage*.  The problem though, is that as far as I can tell: *wounding* isn't established in game terminology. Can we assume it really is synonymous with damage `> 0`? Or am I reading a little too much into the explanatory text?

Comment: This question raises a related question about damage reduction (-3) from Heavy Armor Master Feat and this same question.  If a wererat were to hit for 3 or less damage, does the "hit" still pass the infection?  Perhaps that is a part of this question.  Your call.

Comment: Related questions: [Does dealing 0 damage to a concentrating spellcaster require a saving throw?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/111856/33569), [Does a zero-damage attack still count as a hit?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/95777/33569), [Am I hit when I have immunity?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/99534/33569), [If a poisoned arrow's piercing damage is reduced to 0, do you still get poisoned?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/144839/33569), [If a monk reduces damage to 0 using Deflect Missiles, does the attack still hit?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/119987/33569)

Comment: One more related question: [Does the Tempest cleric's Thunderbolt Strike feature still work if the target is immune to lightning damage?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/130774/33569)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

#### No. They need to *Hit*.

I think you're reading too much into *wounding*.
There's no reason I can think of, in terms of defined game terms, to think that *wounding* refers to *damaging* vs. *hitting*. In other words, the rules don't tell us to prefer one over the other. In general.

However, flip back a few pages: "Player Characters as Lycanthropes" says, in part

> A humanoid **hit** by an attack that carries the curse of lycanthropy must succeed [on a save]... or be cursed. (MM. p.207, emphasis mine.)

There it is, as you first described: the save against cursing is part of the "*Hit*" clause and comes into play whenever a bite hits, even if it hits for no damage.

---

Some have expressed concern about what hit points represent, and whether a zero-damage hit is an injury or not. That way lies madness, I think, and we don't need to go there as *Hit* is a defined term.