# Does the Tempest cleric's Thunderbolt Strike feature still work if the target is immune to lightning damage?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, cleric, immunities

[Tempest Domain clerics](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/cleric#TempestDomain) (PHB, p. 62) get the Thunderbolt Strike feature at 6th level:

> At 6th level, when you deal lightning damage to a Large or smaller creature, you can also push it up to 10 feet away from you.

**What happens if a Level 6+ Tempest Cleric deals lightning damage to a lightning-immune Large (or smaller) creature? Can the cleric still push the creature, or not?**

Comment: Related: [Does a zero damage attack still count as a hit](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/95777/does-a-zero-damage-attack-still-count-as-a-hit), [Does dealing zero damage to a concentrating spellcaster require a saving throw?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/111856/does-dealing-0-damage-to-a-concentrating-spellcaster-require-a-saving-throw)

Comment: Related questions: [Am I hit when I have immunity?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/99534/33569), [If a poisoned arrow's piercing damage is reduced to 0, do you still get poisoned?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/144839/33569), [If a monk reduces damage to 0 using Deflect Missiles, does the attack still hit?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/119987/33569), [Do lycanthropes need to do damage in order to inflict the curse?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/78814/33569)

Comment: One more related question: [Does the Tempest cleric's Thunderbolt Strike feature still work if the target is immune to lightning damage?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/130774/33569)

Answer (score 22):

## No, you can't push a Lightning-Immune Creature using the *Thunderbolt Strike* Feature.

As I read the feature and understand the mechanics, an immune creature cannot take damage from whatever it is immune to. Therefore, effects which depend on *damage* cannot take place against said creatures.

I think this would be a fine interpretation if the description read "when you hit a creature with a spell that deals Lightning Damage", because there's no requirement in that description that actually requires the creature to take damage, but here, I don't think that's the case.

The alternative reading is to infer that Immune Creatures "reduce damage by 100%", implying that the creature takes "0 damage", and thus still qualifies. But I think that's a weird reading, and I think my overall conclusion, that immune creatures do not trigger "when damaged" effects, stands. My interpretation is also supported by Crawford, who asserted that [taking 0 damage means taking no damage](https://twitter.com/jeremyecrawford/status/859637863188713472), and [specifically used this feature](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/859647033552064513) as an example of an effect that would not trigger on a creature immune to the damage type.

Comment: There's a Crawford tweet that says that taking 0 damage is the same as taking no damage.

Comment: Here's the Crawford tweet: ["Taking 0 damage is the same as taking no damage."](https://twitter.com/jeremyecrawford/status/859637863188713472) And the followup, in response to someone asking about this exact case (a Tempest cleric pushing a creature): ["If you took no damage, you didn't take any damage."](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/859647033552064513)

Comment: Well, technically you still deal damage, but your target does not take any damage due to its resistance.

Answer (score 2):

## I would rule "No"

The spell specifically says *when* you do damage, you can also push it away, meaning the damage has to be dealt to the creature in order for the pushback to happen.

*However...*

If the player was trying to say, push the creature off a cliff by using the pushback feature, I'd probably allow it as one-off rule-of-cool type thing!