# Is zero damage considered to be actual damage?

Tags: dnd-5e

In D&D, are effects from damage applied even if the damage is zero?

Comment: Very related on [Does dealing 0 damage to a concentrating spellcaster require a saving throw?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/111856)

Comment: Can you provide a specific example of what you're asking about? While brevity is acceptable, providing a clear example and much more detail give us a better chance at solving your issue. And the answer might be dependent on what the ability says as different abilities might work in different ways.

Comment: _"are effects from damage applied even if the damage is zero?"_ -- I would say that the "very related" post is essentially a duplicate. The accepted answer directly addresses the question of applying effects from damage if the amount of data is 0. I.e. you don't. Damage effects only occur if the damage is non-zero.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: @Fifth_H0r5eman: [Don't answer in comments (including partial or speculative answers).](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6533/should-users-refrain-from-answers-or-partial-answers-in-comments)

Comment: More related questions: [Does a zero-damage attack still count as a hit?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/95777/33569), [Am I hit when I have immunity?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/99534/33569), [If a poisoned arrow's piercing damage is reduced to 0, do you still get poisoned?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/144839/33569), [If a monk reduces damage to 0 using Deflect Missiles, does the attack still hit?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/119987/33569), [Do lycanthropes need to do damage in order to inflict the curse?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/78814/33569)

Comment: One more related question: [Does the Tempest cleric's Thunderbolt Strike feature still work if the target is immune to lightning damage?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/130774/33569)

Comment: Also related (and a duplicate of what the title of this question is asking but not what the body of this question is asking): Does something count as “dealing damage” if its damage is reduced to zero?
](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/178652/does-something-count-as-dealing-damage-if-its-damage-is-reduced-to-zero)