# Can an attack do 0 damage if the hit creature is not immune?

Tags: dnd-5e, damage

I'm going to use the [Giant Fire Beetle](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/giant-fire-beetle) (CR0) as an example.

On a hit, it does 1d6-1 damage. If it rolls a 1 on damage, the -1 would reduce that to 0. Would this attack actually do 0 damage, or would it bottom out at 1?

Comment: Various related questions: [Does something count as “dealing damage” if its damage is reduced to zero?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/178652/14878) | [Does dealing 0 damage to a concentrating spellcaster require a saving throw?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/111856/14878) | [Does a zero-damage attack still count as a hit?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/95777/14878)